# Unwanted printing that occurs before the button is pressed REACT

Tags: reactjs

Before I press the button, the word 'SMALL' already appears (the 'BIG' does appear correctly when I enter a large number .. and then I press the button ..)
thanks

```
function Bif(props){
    const t=props.t;
    let prin=''; 
    if(t>25){
          prin='Big';
    }else{
          prin='small'
        }   
    return(
        <span>  {prin} </span>
    );
}
```

---

return(

```
        <input onChange={put} type="text"/>
        <button onClick={clickS}>click</button>
        <span>{view}</span>
       <Bif t={view}/>
    </div>
);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You made a function as a component so while rendering you are calling that function and `small` is in `else` condition, so it will print.

So call that function only when you click the button.